# ExecAction.spec.containers.livenessProbe.exec.command of type string

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, livenessprobe

Below is the code:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-probe
  labels:
    app: probe
    rel: stable
spec:
  containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
    
    args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - touch /tmp/healthy; sleep 30; rm -rf /tmp/healthy; sleep 600    
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - cat:
        - /tmp/healthy
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```

---

that gives error:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "file.pod.yml": Pod in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Pod: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field ExecAction.spec.containers.livenessProbe.exec.command of type string
```

---

on running `kubectl create -f file.pod.yml  --save-config`

How to resolve this error?

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"27", GitVersion:"v1.27.4", GitCommit:"fa3d7990104d7c1f16943a67f11b154b71f6a132", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-07-19T12:20:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Kustomize Version: v5.0.1
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"27", GitVersion:"v1.27.3", GitCommit:"25b4e43193bcda6c7328a6d147b1fb73a33f1598", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-06-14T09:47:40Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Which version of k8s are you using? Is this a local, bare metal o cloud version?

Comment: @Hackerman minikube version: v1.31.1
commit: fd3f3801765d093a485d255043149f92ec0a695f running on ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @Hackerman updated in query

Comment: In your command, you have `- cat:` - try without the `:` after `cat`. And (if that doesn't work) you might also try it as a single string, i.e. `command: "cat /tmp/healthy"`

Comment: I was about to add the same, remove the colon from the cat

Comment: it works after the changes